# Convert alphanumeric to nchar() in Oracle

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I have a requirement which has a stored procedure and query used alternatively or in parallel.

I have 1 parameter (input variable with type `Nchar(64)`). Now I am run into the issue where stored procedure accepts the input without `''` and query accepts the input with `''`.

For E.g

To run stored procedure I use

```
Procedure sp1(edata);
Execute sp1(12rfg54)  //Input is a nchar and an alphanumerice
```

To run through query

```
select * from table where edata = param1  // where I will pass as '12rfg54'
```

I am calling both from Crystal Reports.

I need to have a common way where I need to pass in only one format with `''` or without `''` but couldn't get the way

Comment: Have you tried calling the procedure with N text literals? e.g. `sp1(n'12rfg54')`

Comment: @kfinity thanks for reply, no didn't try, sure will try and let you know

Comment: @kfinity I am running through sql developer but not working, any other way

Comment: Is there a test case that reproduces the issue without Crystal Reports?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson issue still open and not solved, problem is need a single way to input the value to procedure, that can suite either procedure or query dynamically